# SQL add a counter row

Tags: php, sql

I'd like to add a counter to my website.

I am currently using php and mysql.

An example would be a total count of people who logged in my website.

The structure would look like this

```
|Total User Logins|
|                1|
```

If a user logs in though, I'd like to do this

```
|Total User Logins|
|                2|
```

How would I do this? At the moment it only creates a new row, which is not what I am after.

This is what I tried to do:

```
mysql_query(" UPDATE `Statistics` SET `Success`= `Success` + 1 WHERE 1 ");
```

^ this works on the phpmyadmin panel. But does not work on the php script.

**Thanks**

Comment: and we wish you happy coding in doing so. Come back when you have coded something.

Comment: "How would I do this?" ... you first do this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/2960971

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added the code.

Comment: you need to be more specific in the `WHERE` clause, as to the specific column. That's why your code failed you.

Comment: and where is your `Success` column? Your question is way too unclear for me.

Comment: ok I decided to post something for you below. You can base yourself on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific in the `WHERE` clause, as to the specific column that is to be updated. That's why your code failed you and is creating a new row each time.

I.e.:

```
mysql_query(" UPDATE `Statistics` SET `Success`= `Success` + 1 WHERE column_x = 'y' ");
```

Side note: `column_x` could be `User` as per what you posted for column names. I didn't see one called `Success`. The `y` is an example also. Use the value from the given row you wish to update.

This is purely an example, given you seem to have left out some important details.

By the way, the api you're using is quite old. It is recommended that you move over to either the mysqli_ or PDO api as soon as possible and preferably with a prepared statement. This will help safeguard against a possible SQL injection should user input be involved or any other method such as an `href` through a GET method.

Comment: There are no rows though, the only row there is only the first one. It is just a database that I would like to use to register user logins and failed user logins (this is for later usage to make a nice chart.js chart).

Comment: I also tried to use this `UPDATE Statistics SET Success = Success + 1 WHERE Success = '1' `, and as always, it works on the phpmyadminpanel but not on the php script.

Comment: Yeah, I found out the error. The problem was that I was not selecting the correct database. Sorry, I should pay more attention to this kind of thing.

Comment: @A.Dato no worries, glad to see it worked out in the end, *cheers*